# telerik list box restriction on number of item

Tags: asp.net, listbox, telerik

i have 2 rad list box one is source and another is destination .
i want to restrict user as that he/she cant be transfer more than 2 value ,
means if the destination list having 2 items than it'll not take another one but if we remove one item its again allow the user to transfer only one.
thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your question? What problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into this client side event: OnClientTransferred

[Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listbox-onclienttransferred.html)

So once this event is trigger you can call the function "get_destinationListBox()" and do a count on the numbers of items. if the number is less than 2 then allow the transfer, if it is 2 or bigger then probably you would need to transfer that item back to the source list.